# How to correctly wrap this code in IIFE or use a different method

Tags: javascript

I want to restrict this code from the other, because I do not want to use a global variable, `var targetElement;` it should only be visible in the IIFE area.
I tried to do this, but when I click on `checkbox`, an error pops up, and this is logical, but I do not know how to do it correctly to make it work.

How does my code work?

---

Activate `checkbox`, => access to editing is allowed. Select the cell => the text falls into `input`. Change the text, press `apply` => the text is changed.

---

```
    <table id="tableCinema" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="1" >
        <tr>
            <th >Type</th>
            <th >Name</th>
            <th >Time</th>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>
            <td >1</td><td >*</td><td >*</td>
        </tr>                           
    </table>

    Change: <input id="changes" type="checkbox" name=""
    onclick="eventsInTable()"><br>

    Get text for change: <input id="changeText" type="text" name="" value="">

    <button id="applyToChanges">Apply</button>
```

---

```
var targetElement;

var inputChangeText = document.getElementById('changeText');
var applyChanges = document.getElementById('applyToChanges');

applyChanges.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (targetElement) {
    targetElement.textContent = inputChangeText.value;
  }
}, false);

//change text
var changeText = function(e) {
  inputChangeText.value = e.target.textContent;
  targetElement = e.target;
}

//allow to change
function eventsInTable() {
    var checkBoxChanges = document.getElementById('changes');
    var table = document.getElementById('tableCinema');

    if (checkBoxChanges.checked) {
        table.addEventListener('click', changeText, false);
    } else {
        table.removeEventListener('click', changeText, false);
        alert("You haven't access to change");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that 'pops up'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call it from the HTML attribute, then it must be globally available, however, it's possible to keep your global pollution to a single global variable, and put everything else as properties on that.

```
window.MyNamespace = (function() {
   // your protected code

   // return an object that has whatever you want to access
   return {
     eventsInTable: myLocalEventsInTableFunction
     // other stuff
   }
})();
```

Then have your handler call via the namespace.

```html
Change: <input id="changes" type="checkbox" name=""
  onclick="MyNamespace.eventsInTable()"><br>
```

Comment: It is important to note that it works well without the `window.` prefix, just write `let MyNamespace = (function() {...` .

Comment: @Elad: True, as long as they're executing in the global scope.